# What is this plugin for album gallery?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am working on designing my WordPress based website.

I want to design it as per the following page -
https://www.stanseatonphotography.co.uk/weddings/weddings-gallery/

If you go inside any album, you will see that all the pictures are arranged in row-wise and if you click any picture, the picture will open in full-screen and slider feature will be enabled. I am looking for the same album gallery plugin.

Do you know what is it?

Comment: i don't even think, this is a wordpress site...

Comment: Hi @Argee, thanks for your comment. Do you know how that site was built and how to do the same with wordpress? Can I get same type of album gallery with slideshow plugin? If you see when one single image is clicked to the full screen, it still shows the album url in the address bar instead of the image link. But in wordpress album galleries I am not able to achieve it. Any help?

Comment: Hi, the main problem was with my theme - "Moments". That was causing the problem. I switched to other theme and I am now able to achieve everything!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **Gallery Lightbox** Plugin
This link will guide you through the installation bit.
[Gallery Lightbox plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/gallery-lightbox-slider/)

Comment: Hi Welrico, thanks a lot for your help! Even "Album and Image Gallery Plus Lightbox" plugin also supports the same, but when I am opening the picture full screen, the navigation arrows are disappearing. I can see the arrows for a second while the picture is zoomed to the full screen, but when the picture is in full size the arrows have disappeared. Do you know the reason? My wordpress version - 5.4.2. Thanks again.

Comment: Navigation arrows are disappearing because it appear on hover, try changing hover settings or Try using image Carousel plugin  [link](https://wordpress.org/plugins/image-carousel/)